# Wait for elements to load before opening dropdown list/update dropdown list dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to dynamically update a dropdown list based on the value of another list. I've attached an `onblur` event to make a  server call before I populate the second list with it's values. It happens that when I click on the first list and then click on the second, the loaded elements aren't being displayed correctly.

Here's a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/4yktopux/

Comment: I did not understand what you mean with "the loaded elements aren't being displayed correctly". Could you be more explicit. What I see when I run your link is that on every blur the cities are added without clearing the second dropdownlist before (so after blur twice I have: City1 - City2 - City3 - City1 - City2 - City3)... is this your problem?

Comment: I didn't put too much effort on the example, but what you have to do to reproduce the error is to click on the first list and then click on the second one right after. Don't mind about the data being added. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using the blur event which requires you to move off of the first list.

When you click the second list the blur event fires and begins the load, but the click event also fires on the second list, which is currently empty. That's why it drops down an empty list.

Instead of the blur, use the change event so you don't require users to click a second time to see results.

Comment: Worked for me. I hadn't thought about using the change event, thanks! But the issue remains there, nevertheless. The dropdown list should be able to display correctly even if the elements were added after I clicked on the list. There should be a way to refresh it without clicking out and in again.